# Phone Number input field accept only number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I’ve been working on anocode design studio landing page, and I'm currently tackling the phone number validation. I want to make sure that only numbers are accepted in the phone number field. Here's the part of the code I've been working on for this. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated!

Feel free to provide more details or ask for specific assistance if needed!

I need solution by Javascript only.

```
<form id="enquiryForm" name="wf-form-Enquiry-Form-2" data-name="Enquiry Form" >
    <input type="text" class="form-input-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="Name" data-name="Name" placeholder="Name*" id="name" required="">
    <input type="email" class="form-input-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="Email" data-name="Email" placeholder="Email*" id="Email" required="">
    <input type="text" class="form-input-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="Company" data-name="Company" placeholder="Company*" id="Company" required="">
    <input type="text" class="form-input-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="Phone" data-name="Phone" placeholder="Phone" id="Phone" required="">
    <textarea id="Project-Detail" name="Project-Detail" maxlength="5000" data-name="Project Detail" placeholder="Tell us about your project" class="form-input-field text-area w-input"></textarea>
    <div class="w-embed">
        <input type="hidden" class="button-position" name="Position" value="">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Book Free Call" data-wait="Please wait..." class="button red-btn form w-button">
</form>
```

Comment: You Can Refer to this problem it has various answer
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be helpful for you:

```
<input type="text" id="phoneNumber" oninput="validateNumber(this)">
```

Script:

```
function validateNumber(input) {
  // Remove non-numeric characters from the input value
  let cleanedValue = input.value.replace(/\D/g, '');

  // Update the input value with the cleaned value
  input.value = cleanedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Target the input type like this

```
const phoneInput = document.getElementById('Phone');
```

Now Create a function for this. This will check regex exp.

```
function validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  const phoneRegex = /^\d+$/;
  return phoneRegex.test(phoneNumber);
}
```

Now create an event to detect the input number.

```
phoneInput.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  // Get phone number
  const phoneNumber = event.target.value;

  // Validate number
  const isValid = validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

  // Check validation
  if (!isValid) {
    console.log('Please enter a valid phone number.');
  } else {
    phoneInput.setCustomValidity('');
  }
});
```

Comment: @DarkBee, yes you are right, but OP specifically want to accept only numbers.

Comment: Guess that's actually correct, but seems like an UX issue. OP should use a masked input to guide  the user